# How to pass a variable from a child component template to a parent component in angular2?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template, angular2-directives

I have created 4 components. They are 
1.Icon component
2.Toolbar Component
3.Design Component and
4.Tree Component

In **Icon component** I have imported around 10 icons from css and assigned a value for it.

In **toolbar component** I have rendered those 10 icons by using **Icon component**.

In Design and Tree template I used toolbar component but it will display all 10 icons in both design and tree page. I want to show only a set of icons in design and another set in tree. Is there any way we can restrict what icons should display in Design and Tree in toolbar component.

```
Toolbar.component.ts:
import {Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter} from "@angular/core";

@Component({
selector: 'toolbar',
templateUrl: './toolsbar.template.html'
})

export class ToolBar {

@Output() iconClicked: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();
@Input() page: string;




onClicked(icontype: string): void {
    this.iconClicked.emit(icontype)
}
}
```

Design Template.html
    `<div class="panel-section">
                    <div class="row">
                        <toolbar (iconClicked)="onToolIconClicked($event)" >     </toolbar>
                    </div>`

Toolabar.template.Html

```
<div style="float: right">
<tool-icon [id]="'btn-refresh'" [type]="'refresh'" (iconClicked)="onClicked($event)">
<tool-icon>
<tool-icon [id]="'btn-add'" [type]="'add'" (iconClicked)="onClicked($event)">
<tool-icon>
<tool-icon [id]="'btn-edit'" [type]="'edit'" (iconClicked)="onClicked($event)">
<tool-icon>
<tool-icon [id]="'btn-delete'" [type]="'delete'" (iconClicked)="onClicked($event)">
<tool-icon>
<tool-icon [id]="'btn-import'" [type]="'import'" (iconClicked)="onClicked($event)">
<tool-icon>

<tool-icon [id]="'btn-collapse'" [type]="'collapse'" (iconClicked)="onClicked($event)">
<tool-icon>
<tool-icon [id]="'btn-expandall'" [type]="'expandall'" (iconClicked)="onClicked($event)">
<-tool-icon>
<tool-icon [id]="'btn-expanddiff'" [type]="'expanddiff'" (iconClicked)="onClicked($event)">
<tool-icon>
<tool-icon [id]="'btn-selectall'" [type]="'selectall'" (iconClicked)="onClicked($event)">
<tool-icon>
<tool-icon [id]="'btn-selectnone'" [type]="'selectnone'" (iconClicked)="onClicked($event)">
<tool-icon>
 tool-icon [id]="'btn-selectdiff'" [type]="'selectdiff'" (iconClicked)="onClicked($event)">
<tool-icon>
```

But I want to render any 2 icons only in the design page. Kindly provide some suggestions

Answer (score 1):

In angular 2 for pass a variable from a child component to parent component is used through event with a output property and EventEmitter that implement the pattern observable.

Example in child component you declare a output property

```
@Output() onProductSelected: EventEmitter<any>;
```

and in parent component in template

```
<child-product (onProductSelected)=setProduct($event)></child-product>
```

where $event is the value that you want to pass to parent component

Comment: @alen .. I don't want to pass any event or action .. while one page loads it should display a set of icons and another page should display another set of icons while you are using same toolbar

Comment: But you don't pass a variable from a child to a parent component?

Comment: @allen. I need to pass a variable from a child component template. from design template to toolbar component or toolbar template

Comment: I don't understand, you want to pass variable, you can pass value of variable to other component but variable explain me

Comment: Ya my mistake a value need to pass but I don't want a event to pass  . I need a string value to be passed ..